# Can someone explain this Python (variable=type, variable=list=list etc.)?

Tags: python

I've been looking at some code for the Python-chess module and am seeing syntax I've never come across.

```
Color = bool
COLORS = [WHITE, BLACK] = [True, False]
COLOR_NAMES = ["black", "white"]

PieceType = int
PIECE_TYPES = [PAWN, KNIGHT, BISHOP, ROOK, QUEEN, KING] = range(1, 7)
PIECE_SYMBOLS = [None, "p", "n", "b", "r", "q", "k"]
PIECE_NAMES = [None, "pawn", "knight", "bishop", "rook", "queen", "king"]
```

1) What is the point of the `Color = bool` line?

2) How can `COLOURS` be assigned to two lists? (and the same with `PIECE_TYPES`?)

Full code: [https://github.com/niklasf/python-chess/blob/master/chess/**init**.py](https://github.com/niklasf/python-chess/blob/master/chess/__init__.py)
Relevant stuff starts at line 41

Comment: Can you link to the full code if its on Git? The bishop can only live on the color they start on as they move diagonally. Perhaps is a confirmation step? More likely it's to design the board.

Comment: I think the colors refer to the pieces themselves, not the color of the square they are on.

Comment: Hi Charlie, welcome to SO. Consider update in your title after reading https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. This will help keep SO easy to search and obtain information from. Good luck!

Comment: @chepner @Jim Thanks - I think I understand what the code does now. But why would you want to do it? For example, why would having a variable `color` assigned to `bool` be useful?

Comment: It's a use-specific alias for `bool`, although one rarely has to refer to type names explicitly in Python. The least contrived example I can think of would be if you wanted to create a default dict of piece colors; `pieces = defaultdict(Color)` might read better than `pieces = defaultdict(bool)`.

Comment: @chepner Ok, thank you for your help - much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It's just a combination of sequence unpacking and chained assignment. It's equivalent to

```
WHITE = True
BLACK = False
COLORS = [WHITE, BLACK]
```

`Color = bool` just makes `Color` refer to the same value as the name `bool` (namely, the built-in type `bool`). The same goes for `PieceType`; presumably both are used later.

A less hackish implementation would use the `enum` module. Something like

```
from enum import Enum, IntEnum

class Color(IntEnum):
    BLACK = 0
    WHITE = 1

class Piece(Enum):
    PAWN = ("p", "pawn")
    KNIGHT = ("n", "knight")
    BISHOP = ("b", "bishop")
    ROOK = ("r", "rook")
    QUEEN = ("q", "queen")
    KING = ("k", "king")
```

Comment: Side note: not a fan of using a boolean for what should be a 2 case enum. There's no reason to prevent your chess engine from being able to handle 4 way chess, when the necessary modification is so small.

Comment: Absolutely; I am planning to update the answer with an example `Enum` implementation, although as it isn't the OP's code it is only tangentially relevant.

Comment: Yep. If I have the time, I like to add these "tangentially related" tidbits onto my answer. It just takes the question and learning to the next step

Answer (score 0):

`Color` is a variable that holds the type `bool`.

The second line is best interpreted in 2 parts.  We evaluate assignments right to left, so first it creates a list of two variables that are assigned the values of `True` and `False` respectively.  Then those get stored as `COLORS`:

```
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 12 2018, 13:43:14)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> Color = bool
>>> COLORS = [WHITE, BLACK] = [True, False]
>>> COLOR_NAMES = ["black", "white"]
>>> COLORS
[True, False]
>>> Color
<class 'bool'>
>>> WHITE
True
>>> BLACK
False
>>>
```